# How do I limit the number of SQL results but also allow full width?

Tags: php, css, sql

I have 10 movies on one page. I want 5 movies on each row. However, I also want to give the div enough width to allow the 5 movies ability to stretch. Each movie will have images on top of them. The images are friends of that user. These friends are on top of a movie because they are friends with that user and have liked that specific movie. These images require the movies needing more space.

I have included an image to help illustrate my problem:

[image: Visual Aid of Project]

The red border represents the space I have to move around. I only want 5 movies and their respective elements. However, some of the elements from the second row are linking to the first row.

**Question:** How do I give each row space, but also limit each row to 5 elements?

**EDIT**

I found a solution to the problem. These movies are created by a PHP *while loop*. Each time the while loop occurs, `$number` increases by one. I created the following *if statement*:

```
if($number == 5) {
echo "<br>";
}

$number++;
```

Is this a good solution? The table idea is certainly good, I would only be worried about styling issues...

Comment: I think you will be better off putting your elements to a table

Comment: @cha Is there any SQL solution to this problem? For example, something like: $db->query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5,5");

Comment: This isn't a SQL issue, this is an issue with how you're displaying the results on the page. You can use a table as suggested (5 columns) or you could use CSS to style the elements accordingly.

Comment: SQL shouldn't know or care about the page layout outside of paging, and even then it should just be a 'From row X get me Y more rows'

Comment: you can also enclose the Picture, running time and classification of each movie to each separate `div` to prevent them from separating

Answer (score -1):

There are a bunch of ways to do this. One simple route would be to make a table with HTML:

```
<table class="movies-row">
  <tr>
    <td>movie-1</td>
    <td>movie-2</td>
    <td>movie-3</td>
    <td>movie-4</td>
    <td>movie-5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>movie-6</td>
    <td>movie-7</td>
    <td>movie-8</td>
    <td>movie-9</td>
    <td>movie-10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

...and then declare a CSS class in your stylesheet to full up the whole row:

```
.movies-row {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```